# Sum different lines of a Matrix using SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I need to sum the values from the months such as highlighted in the Picture, is there a way to do it without VBA? It will repeat itslef a few times.

First I tried using `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9=2004)*(A1:M1>=4)*(E6:M6))`, with this solution it's possible to change the year and month just fine, the problem is that if I try using the entire matrix `(B2:M9)`it fails.

Should I think about another approach or is there a way to make that last matrix related to the year or cell (something like {=E1+5} returning E6).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=2004)*(B1:M1>=4),B2:M9)
```